# Cassandra - query not returning result with frozen type

Tags: cassandra

I have created a cassandra table using few `primary datatypes` and a frozen type `address_type`.

```
CREATE TYPE address_type (
                  first_name text,
                  last_name text,
                  address_line1 text,
                  address_line2 text
              );

CREATE TABLE user (
              id text,
              active_profile boolean,
              addresses frozen<address_type>,
              PRIMARY KEY (id)
          );
```

And indexed the columns `addresses` because I want to select few `resultset` based on `address_type.first_name`.

```
CREATE INDEX ON user (addresses) ;
```

Finally this is my query which returns **0 rows**.

```
select * from user where addresses = {first_name:'test2'};
```

When I tried

```
select * from "user" where addresses > {first_name:'test2'};
```

Which resulted in

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided operators: 'addresses > <value>'"
```

Can someone help me? Where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's insert some data :

```
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO user (id , addresses) VALUES ('user_0', {first_name:'Ashraful', last_name:'Islam'});
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO user (id , addresses) VALUES ('user_1', {first_name:'Ashraful'});
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM user ;

 id     | active_profile | addresses
--------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 user_1 |           null |    {first_name: 'Ashraful', last_name: null, address_line1: null, address_line2: null}
 user_0 |           null | {first_name: 'Ashraful', last_name: 'Islam', address_line1: null, address_line2: null}
```

**Since addresses is frozen type. you can't query with a piece of a frozen field. You have to provide full value of addresses**

Example :

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM user WHERE addresses = {first_name:'Ashraful', last_name:'Islam'} ;

 id     | active_profile | addresses
--------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 user_0 |           null | {first_name: 'Ashraful', last_name: 'Islam', address_line1: null, address_line2: null}

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM user WHERE addresses = {first_name: 'Ashraful'} ;

 id     | active_profile | addresses
--------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 user_1 |           null | {first_name: 'Ashraful', last_name: null, address_line1: null, address_line2: null}

(1 rows)
```

Comment: But yeah, I am expecting the both the values. You are saying that is not possible in cassandra

Comment: @Suganthan frozen stored as compact blob, so `{first_name: 'Ashraful'}` will match with exact blob value of addresses

Comment: got it, but this is really a weird design, we should be very careful before choosing frozen type

Comment: @Suganthan yes, you should